# Adapt code to copy/paste .zip and .tar.gzip files?

Tags: c, linux

**Introduction**

I'm writing my own `cp` program. With the code I currently have I'm able to copy and paste files.

**Code**

```
char *buf;
int fd;
int ret;
struct stat sb;
FILE *stream;

/*opening and getting size of file to copy*/
fd = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
if(fd == -1)
{
   perror("open");
   return 1;
}
/*obtaining size of file*/
ret = fstat(fd,&sb);
if(ret)
{
    perror("stat");
    return 1;
}

/*opening a stream for reading/writing file*/
stream fdopen(fd,"rb");
if(!stream)
{
     perror("fdopen");
     return 1;
}

/*allocating space for reading binary file*/
buf = malloc(sb.st_size);

/*reading data*/
if(!fread(buf,sb.st_size,1,stream))
{
    perror("fread");
    return 1;
}

/*writing file to a duplicate*/
fclose(stream);
stream = fopen("duplicate","wb");

if(!fwrite(buf,sb.st_size,1,stream))
{
    perror("fwrite");
    return 1;
}

 fclose(stream);
 close(fd);
 free(buf);
 return 0;
```

**The problem**

I'm unable to copy and paste .zip files and .tar.gz files. If i alter the code and give an extension such as 'duplicate.zip' (assuming im copying a zip file) such as .zip and then try and copy a .zip file
everything is copied, however the new duplicated file does not act like a zip file and when i use cat it outputs nothing and this error when i attempt to unzip it anyway:

> End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
>     a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
>     latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
>     the last disk(s) of this archive.

So how do i go about copying zip and pasting zip files and also .tar.gz files. Any pointers will be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use your program to copy other non-text files, e.g. *.exe, does that work?

Comment: have you tried using fgets and fputs ?

Comment: BTW: `buf = malloc(sb.st_size * sizeof buf);` -->> `buf = malloc(sb.st_size * sizeof *buf);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [AlexP's notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51117134/14660)...

```
/*obtaining size of file*/
ret = fstat(fd,&sb);
if(ret)
{
    perror("stat");
    return 1;
}

// ...some code...

/*allocating space for reading binary file*/
buf = malloc(sb.st_size);

/*reading data*/
if(!fread(buf,sb.st_size,1,stream))
{
    perror("fread");
    return 1;
}
```

You have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) here. If the file size changes between your `fstat` call and `malloc` or `fread` you will read too much or too little of the file.

Fixing this leads us to the next issue, you're slurping the entire file into memory. While this might work for small files, it is extremely inefficient with your memory on large ones. For very large files it might be too large for a single `malloc`, and you're not checking if your `malloc` succeeds.

Instead, read and write the file a piece at a time. And read until there isn't any more to read.

```
uint8_t *buffer[4096]; // 4K buffer
size_t num_read;
while( (num_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), sizeof(buffer), in)) != 0 ) {
    if( fwrite( buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), num_read, out ) == 0 ) {
        perror("fwrite");
    }
}
```

This avoids the race condition by not having to call `fstat` in the first place. And it avoids allocating a potentially enormous hunk of memory. Instead it can all be done [on the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation).

I've used `uint8_t` to get a hunk of bytes. It's [a standard fixed width integer type from stdint.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed-width_integer_types). You can also use `unsigned char` to read bytes, and that's probably what `uint8_t` really is, but `uint8_t` makes it explicit.

Comment: Thank you for the information, i was unaware of the race condition in the program and using fstat.

Answer (score 1):

- You are using `malloc()` incorrectly. You want to allocate `sb.st_size` bytes.

  ```
  malloc(sb.st_size * sizeof buf)
  ```

  should be

  ```
  malloc(sb.st_size)
  ```
- The use of `fread()` is dubious *and* you are throwing away the result of `fread()`. Instead of

  ```
  if(!fread(buf,sb.st_size,1,stream))
  ```

  you should have

  ```
  size_t num_bytes_read = fread (buf, 1, sb.st_size, stream);
  if (num_bytes_read < sb.st_size)
  ```
- You are using `strlen()` incorrectly. The content of `buf` is not guaranteed to be a string; and anyway *you already know* how many bytes you have in `buf`: `sb.st_size`. (Because if `fread()` returned a smaller number of bytes read you got angry and terminated the process.) So instead of

  ```
  fwrite(buf,strlen(buf),1,stream)
  ```

you should have

```
    fwrite (buf, 1, sb.st_size, stream)
```

Comment: Thank you! i'll be adding these adjustments to my program.